# Put an array in to a column

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sql-server-2008, ef-code-first

I want to use EF code first to create a column into a table `Task`, which is an array. How?

```
public class Task
{
     // my presumption code
     public string[] Attempts { get; set; }
```

The `Attempts` has

```
   AttemptsMetadata---maybe string
   Time            ---DataTime
   Answered        ---bool
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a property to be used in the code (and mark as ignore) and other property to be used in code.

**EDITED**

```
public class Task
{
    [Ignore]
    public string[] Attempts { get; set; }

    public string AttemptsMetadata
    {
        get
        {
            return Attempts != null && Attempts.Any()
                ? Attempts.Aggregate((ac, i) => ";" + ac + i).Substring(1)
                : null;
        }
        set { Attempts = value.Split(';'); }
    }
}
```

**PS**:
This strategy has a one flaw. When you use repository expressions you cannot use the ignore property. But I never find another way to do so.

Comment: How about others such as Time? It is not a string. I mean should I define Attempt as an object rather than a string array?

Comment: If you have a array of primitive types, you can use this approach, but if you using a non primitive type I will advise you to create a table to store this info and you use foreign key to create a relationship. In LINQ this relationship will be represented like a ICollection<> property (it's not a array but is very closer to).